# DataGridViewComboBoxCell inactive item painting

Tags: .net, datagridview, combobox

We're trying to alter the DataGridViewComboBoxCell so that when the user expands the dropdown menu, inactive items are displayed in grey text.

I've found out how to do this by creating a new object, which inherits from DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl.

The problem with this, is that I'm not sure how to tell the comboBoxCell, or column, to use this EditingControl, when the user clicks on the cell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement an Owner Drawn ComboBox. Take a look at this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/combobox/ownerdrawncombobox.aspx

Comment: Yep, I've implemented one of these. The problem is, there is no DrawItem method on a combobox cell.. :(